# Azure get token with JavaScript Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, oauth

This is my code:

```
$scope.getToken = function() {
    // $scope.connect()
    $http(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: $scope.urlToGetToken, 
            params: $scope.authParams, 
            headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }
    ).
    success(function(data){
        console.log("whatever" + data);
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(config);
    })

    $scope.authParams = {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: '03b****************ba-931c-3b19f204c736',
        code: 'AAABAAAAv*********b',
        redirect_uri: 'localhost:8080'
    }
```

Despite `grant_type` parameter is there I am getting `400` with the following error:

```
  "AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter:
 'grant_type'. ↵Trace ID:
```

What is this all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params` is used to send data in `querysting`.

Use `data` to send data in post body.

`$http({method: 'POST', url:$scope.urlToGetToken, data:$scope.authParams, headers:{`